# Inner looping with Terraform

Tags: github, terraform

Using the Terraform (v0.9.6) GitHub Provider, how can one separately assign multiple distinct issue labels to a list of GitHub repositories while using one resource?

With another language I'd probably write something along the lines of:

```
for i in repos {
   for j in tags[i] {
   make tag j on repo i
   }
}
```

In this example below I am adding multiple tags to a single repository. The `map` keys are the repos, and the values are a list of strings.:

```
variable "issue-labels" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    "repo_0" = "tag1, tag2, tag3"
    "repo_1" = "tag4"
    "repo_2" = "tag5, tag6"
  }
}


resource "github_issue_label" "issue_labels" {
  count = "${length(split(", ", join(", ", lookup(issue-labels, "my-repo"))))}"
  repository = "my-repo"
  name = "${element(split(", ", join(", ", lookup(issue-labels, "my-repo"))), count.index)}"
  color = "FFFFFF"
}
```

Currently seeking an answer to what feels like an inner loop in terraform. Either finding some way to iterate through the repositories and make multiple resource counts for each, or a workaround involving [interpolation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html) to assign the right repo when we iterate through the total number of labels.

Comment: Similar to https://serverfault.com/questions/833810/terraform-use-nested-loops-with-count

Comment: I too thought this was the same question at first, but the other question is about creating a two-dimensional "matrix" of resources, which ends up being a little different than this scenario where each of the top-level objects (repository) has its own set of second-level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using list variables and other complex structures to "abstract away" resources is not idiomatic and tends to lead to configuration that is hard to read and maintain.

The idiomatic style is to manage repetitive constructs using multiple instances of a child module.

For example, one can make a subdirectory called `repository` that contains a `repository.tf` file such as the following:

```
variable "name" {
}

variable "labels" {
  type = "list"
}

# can instead use github_team_repository here if appropriate
resource "github_repository" "this" {
  name = "${var.name}"
  # ...
}

resource "github_issue_label" "all" {
  count = "${length(var.labels)}"

  repository = "${var.name}"
  name       = "${var.labels[count.index]}"
  color      = "FFFFFF"
}
```

Now in the root module, rather than using variables to define the set of repositories, one can instead instantiate this resource once for each repository:

```
module "foo_repo" {
  source = "./repository"

  name = "foo"
  labels = ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
}

module "bar_repo" {
  source = "./repository"

  name = "bar"
  labels = ["tag4"]
}

module "baz_repo" {
  source = "./repository"

  name = "baz"
  labels = ["tag5", "tag6"]
}
```

With this style, the settings for each repository are kept together in a single module block each, thus making them easy to read and update. Adding a new repository is done by adding a new `module` block.

This style also allows removing a single repository without disturbing all of the ones after it, since the module states are stored by the module name rather than by index into a a list.

The general recommendation here is that `count` should be used sparingly, and that it's usually better to write config explicitly rather than generate it via variables. The result is often easier to read and maintain, and easier to adapt over time as requirements change.

Comment: Two years later is this still idiomatic, noting that Terraform changes fast?